# How do I get VS2010 in XPMode to see SQL server running on the host Win7 OS?

Tags: sql-server-2008, virtual-pc, xp-mode

HI,

I've got Windows XP Mode running on Wndows 7 Professional x64. I have an 
instance of SQL 2008 running on Windows 7 which I would like my copy of 
VS2010b2 Pro running inside WinXPMode to see. However, I cannot figure out the 
right combination of networking and firewall adjustments to make. Below is 
what I've done so far. Can someone help me out with what I've left to do to 
get this working? I've tried working through several solutions for SQL2005 mentioned elsewhere on the site, but still no joy.

Thanks, Dan

- Installed Loopback Adapter on Host OS
- Set up Loopback Adapter to have a static IP address 192.168.3.1 which the 
  VPC network adapter will use as its internet gateway.
- Configured the XP Mode Virtual Machine to use the loopback adapter.
- Gave the network connection in XP mode the static IP address 192.168.3.2. 
  and the default gateway as 192.168.3.1.

At this point I can ping my host OS from my guest OS.

- Added incoming rules to my Win7 firewall for port 1433/TCP and 1434/UDP 
  and also for sqlsrvr.exe
- Opened SQL Server Configuration Manager and Enabled TCP/IP 
  for your SQL Server on my host OS
- Within properties for TCP/IP, added entry for IP 192.168.3.1 on port 1433

However, I still cannot telnet to my host OS port 1433 or 1434 from within 
my guest OS and have run out of ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution myself. For reference, I missed two things in that list above.

1. In SQL Server Config Manager, I didn't also set the IPAll entry in TCP/IP config to receive on port 1433.
2. In the firewall control panel, I didn't double check that the firewall had opened port 1433/TCP and 1434/UDP on the Public network which is what Win7 treats the loopback adapter network as.

I've documented the full set of steps at http://blog.hmobius.com/post/2009/12/24/How-to-get-Windows-7-XP-Mode-Apps-to-talk-to-SQL-2008-on-your-Windows-7-Host-OS.aspx#continue